# Get and choose path Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

This is what I have:

[image: Example]

How do I make it so the label contains the current path to the desktop, and how do I make it so when they hit choose, they can choose an install location, and then set the label to contain that path? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) choose : (id)sender;
{
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];  
if ([panel respondsToSelector:@selector(beginWithCompletionHandler:)]) { 
//Mac OS X 10.6 and later
    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {    // Only if not cancelled
            NSArray *urls = [panel URLs];
            [text setStringValue:[[urls objectAtIndex:0]path]];
            [panel orderOut:nil];  

        }
    }];
}
else{

        NSInteger result    = [panel runModal];
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            NSArray *urls = [panel URLs];
       [text setStringValue:[[urls objectAtIndex:0]path]];
            [panel orderOut:nil];   
        }
}
}  

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Desktop"];
[text setStringvalue: docsDir];
}
```